# New circuitikz is here! And first problem too

Tags: circuitikz

I update my MikTeX yesterday and got new version of the `circuitikz` package! I immediately made short check, if my old `circuitikz` pictures work as at old packet version. So far all test except one gives the same results. Exception is the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=0.25,bipoles/diode/width=0.25}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.25],
\draw
(0,0)       coordinate (T1+)
            node [nigbt,anchor=S,
                  rotate=-90,color=gray]    (igbt2) {}      % IGBT as node, in gray color
(T1+)       to [short,*-]               ++  (0,-0.5) coordinate (D2)
            to [Do,a=D,color=red]           (D2 -| igbt2.D) % diode, in red color
            to [short,-*]                   (igbt2.D)
            to [Do,a=D,color=blue]       ++  (1,0)          % diode, in blue color
            ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Misplaced of the red diode's label happen only in combination of rotated igbt element and at setting diode label with `a=D`. If I replace it with `l=D`, placement of "D" is correct on opposite side of diode. With old packet version it works fine.

Do anyone here have similar experience? Do I miss something?

Comment: Same here also. I tried your code with 0.8.3. It worked smoothly. I did the update. Now does not work with 0.9.0.

Comment: Would you please [report an issue](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues)?

Comment: Yes, please, report an issue. I am quite occupied now, but I'll try to see what's happening as soon as possible.

Comment: ...and it's really puzzling. With `scale=1` and `scale=2` it works. Smells like a subtle thing...

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/202

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the (unreleased) version 0.9.1, which will be released after giving a bit of time for bug reports to come in. In the meantime, you can use the git version you can find on https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/ .

#### previous answer

I *think* I have an answer. It seems that sometime the path direction is not normalized, so I got the wrong position for the anchors.

Try this: edit the file `pgfcirclabel.tex`. Go around line 104, you should see

```
...
\ifnum \pgf@circ@temp < 0
        \pgfmathadd{\pgf@circ@labanc}{180}
        \edef\pgf@circ@labanc{\expandafter\pgf@circ@stripdecimals\pgfmathresult\pgf@nil}
\fi
\ifpgf@circuit@bipole@inverted
...
```

...after the `\fi` on line 104, insert this:

```
\pgfmathmod{\pgf@circ@labanc}{360}
\edef\pgf@circ@labanc{\expandafter\pgf@circ@stripdecimals\pgfmathresult\pgf@nil}
```

and try again. It seems to work for me now, and the patch is logically correct. Can you please check it?

#### Original answer and workaround

It's really puzzling, and I need to dig into the `pgfcircpath.tex` and `pgfcirclabel.tex` code to find what's happening. Notice that if I split the drawing like:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=0.25,bipoles/diode/width=0.25}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.25],
    \draw
    (0,0)       coordinate (T1+)
    node [nigbt,anchor=S, rotate=-90,color=gray]    (igbt2) {}      % IGBT as node, in gray color
    (T1+)       to [short,*-]               ++  (0,-0.5) coordinate (D2);
    \draw
    (D2)        to [Do,a=D,color=red]            (D2 -| igbt2.D) % diode, in red color 
    to [short,-*]                   (igbt2.D)
    to [Do,a=D,color=blue]       ++  (1,0)          % diode, in blue color
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

(which should be completely equivalent) the result is

[image]

...I'm expecting quite a bit of difficult debugging here... :-(

Comment: For new image this is workaround (+1), but for old one means to edit all whit similar image composition. I wish many luck in code digging!

Comment: Yes, it's clearly a bug/regression. Will work on it; if you can open an issue --- better, otherwise I'll do it myself when I find time. Thanks!

Comment: Please, do yourself. I need to register before ... and in such things i ease go to lost :-(

Comment: you should notice me, that you edit your answer ... mow I test fix and it worked. thank you very much.

Comment: @Zarko , I have changed a bit the implementation, and now should catch also negative big angles. Can you check it, please?

Comment: I check new version of fix on small collection of my `circuitikz` images. it works!